# Trying to understand how to make a UpdateOrCreate

Tags: php, laravel

I have a model with the following code:

```
    public static function insertSent($itemId, $currentPackId)
    {
        $itemHistory = new ItemHistory([
            'item_id' => $itemId,
            'pack_id' => $currentPackId,
            'status' => self::SENT,
            'returned_by' => Auth::id()
        ]);

        $itemHistory->save();
    }

    public static function insertReturned($itemId, $currentPackId)
    {
        $itemHistory = new ItemHistory([
            'item_id' => $itemId,
            'pack_id' => $currentPackId,
            'status' => self::RETURNED,
            'returned_by' => Auth::id()
        ]);

        $itemHistory->save();
    }
```

I just added the insertSent and I want to change the insertReturned to a function where it updates a record if it exists or creates it so UpdateOrCreate.

I'm using laravel php

Comment: is the record to find identified by 'item_id' and 'pack_id'?

Comment: Have you tried Laravel's `updateOrCreate` method?

Comment: @lagbox Yes if it exists.

Comment: @ShahlinIbrahim trying to figure out how to write that out. maybe my brain is fried from staring at it too much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can adjust your method to use `updateOrCreate` pretty easily:

```
public static function insertReturned($itemId, $currentPackId)
{
    ItemHistory::updateOrCreate([
        'item_id' => $itemId,
        'pack_id' => $currentPackId,
    ], [
        'status' => self::RETURNED,
        'returned_by' => Auth::id(),
    ]);        
}
```

The first array is what you are looking for. If a record is found fill it with the second array and save. If no record is found merge the first and second array and create the new record.

[Laravel 6.x Docs - Eloquent - Other Creation Methods](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent#other-creation-methods)`updateOrCreate`